# Change whole document font to be a little thicker and more readable

Tags: fonts

The font of my document is too slim, and not very convenient to read when the document is printed.

I want to make the whole document font a little thicker and more easily readable.

I tried to add to the preamable of the LaTeX document the line:

```
\renewcommand{\seriesdefault}{\bfdefault}
```

But then the text font is too bold, and the mathematical equations remain with a slim font.

Adding '`\usepackage{newtxtext}`' to the preamble as suggested below helped improve the text weight, but the mathematical statements (especially the Greece letters) are still with a too slim font weight.

What can be done to improve their font weight to match that of the text?

A minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{load-configurations = abbreviations}
\sisetup{range-units=single}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[raggedright]{titlesec}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{fixmath}

\begin{document}
The binding energy of most atoms ($\sim$\SIrange[range-phrase={--}]{5}{15}{\electronvolt}) is about 5 to 10 times larger than the energy of an optical photon in the NIR region ($\sim$\SIrange[range-phrase={--}]{0.5}{1.5}{\electronvolt}). Some more text here. Bla bla bla. $\mathbf{A}$ and $\phi_{sc}$ are the vector and scalar potentials of the interacting electromagnetic field, and where the Coulomb gouge ($\nabla\cdot\mathbf{A}(\mathbf{r},t)=0$) is considered, $\phi_{sc}(\mathbf{r},t)\equiv\phi_C(\mathbf{r})=-e/4\pi\varepsilon_0 r$ is the Coulomb scalar potential (for simplicity a hydrogen atom is considered). And again some more text here. Bla bla bla bla. In a static external electric field of magnitude $\mathcal{E}_L$ in the x direction, the total potential exerted on a hydrogenic electron is: 

\begin{equation}
\phi_{st}=\frac{e}{4\pi\varepsilon_0 r}-x\mathcal{E}_L
\label{eq:electron_in_laser_field_potential}
\end{equation} %
%
and the corresponding electron electric potential energy, $U_E$, is writen blow but before lets put some more text between the equations in order to make the difference between the font weight of the text and the math (especially the greec symbols) more discernable. Bla bla bla bla bla bla. And now lets give the equation mentioned above which is:%
%   
\begin{equation}
U_E=-e\cdot\phi_{st}=-\frac{e^2}{4\pi\varepsilon_0 r}+ex\mathcal{E}_L
\label{eq:electron_in_laser_field_potential_energy}
\end{equation} %
%
This electric potential energy is shown in the figure below. And much more text goes here. Bla bla bla bla bla. And so on. 
\end{document}
```

Comment: You probably want to simply choose another font which is more to your liking: http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/

Comment: One of many possible fonts which are a bit heavier: `\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}`

Comment: you can't redesign a font on the fly, computer modern is a very light font, perhaps ypou would prefer a Times  Roman clone (`\usepackage{newtxtext}` for example)

Comment: When I add '\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}' to the preamble of the LaTeX document I get 122 errors of: 'Too many math alphabets used in version normal'

Comment: The '\usepackage{newtxtext}' worked for the text, but the math statements and equations remained with the slim font. What can I do to change also their font to the thicker one?

Comment: @user4861528 If you reply to a comment, please prefix the comment with @ followed by the username you want to reply to. If you would add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) we could try to fix the math alphabets problem.

Comment: @samcarter - I added a MWE to the question.

Comment: @user4861528 I don't get any error when I add `\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}` to your MWE. Which tex distribution and version do you have?

Comment: @samcarter I use MiKTex2.9 . With the MWE I get 1 error when I add '\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}' : 'Command \circledS' already defined.

Comment: @user4861528 In addition to the error, you should also get three warnings which tells you which of the packages should be removed. (in addition I would also remove all the other font related packages)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion would be to use another font that is heavier by default.

There are many possible font, the following example uses `charter`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathcal}{normal}{OMS}{xmdcmsy}{m}{n}% use normal mathcal

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{
    load-configurations = abbreviations,
    range-units=single
}

\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[raggedright]{titlesec}

\begin{document}
The binding energy of most atoms ($\sim$\SIrange[range-phrase={--}]{5}{15}{\electronvolt}) is about 5 to 10 times larger than the energy of an optical photon in the NIR region ($\sim$\SIrange[range-phrase={--}]{0.5}{1.5}{\electronvolt}). Some more text here. Bla bla bla. $\mathbf{A}$ and $\phi_{sc}$ are the vector and scalar potentials of the interacting electromagnetic field, and where the Coulomb gouge ($\nabla\cdot\mathbf{A}(\mathbf{r},t)=0$) is considered, $\phi_{sc}(\mathbf{r},t)\equiv\phi_C(\mathbf{r})=-e/4\pi\varepsilon_0 r$ is the Coulomb scalar potential (for simplicity a hydrogen atom is considered). And again some more text here. Bla bla bla bla. In a static external electric field of magnitude $\mathcal{E}_L$ in the x direction, the total potential exerted on a hydrogenic electron is: 
%
\begin{equation}
\phi_{st}=\frac{e}{4\pi\varepsilon_0 r}-x\mathcal{E}_L
\label{eq:electron_in_laser_field_potential}
\end{equation} %
%
and the corresponding electron electric potential energy, $U_E$, is writen blow but before lets put some more text between the equations in order to make the difference between the font weight of the text and the math (especially the greec symbols) more discernable. Bla bla bla bla bla bla. And now lets give the equation mentioned above which is:%
%   
\begin{equation}
U_E=-e\cdot\phi_{st}=-\frac{e^2}{4\pi\varepsilon_0 r}+ex\mathcal{E}_L
\label{eq:electron_in_laser_field_potential_energy}
\end{equation} %
%
This electric potential energy is shown in the figure below. And much more text goes here. Bla bla bla bla bla. And so on. 


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For some reason adding the lines: '\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}' and '\SetMathAlphabet{\mathcal}{normal}{OMS}{xmdcmsy}{m}{n}' didn't work for me, and also the text remained with a slim font weight. However, the line '\usepackage{newtxtext}'  did work but only for the text and not the math. What is the problem with my system?

Comment: "didn't work" is not a very precise description. Do you get any errors or warnings? Can you show your `.log` file?

Comment: No errors or warnings. Just doesn't give thicker text. Do you mean to copy the entire .log to the question?

Comment: @user4861528 Yes, if the log file is too long for the question, you could use https://pastebin.com/

Comment: I copied the log file to the window at the site of the link you provided.

Comment: @user4861528 Can you give me the link to your log file?

Comment: Sorry. The link is: https://pastebin.com/rSTw2nqJ

Comment: @user4861528 Your logfile shows that you are overwriting the font by loading other font packages afterwards, e.g. `lmodern`. If you have a look at my answer, I removed all other font packages to avoid this problem.

Comment: I need the package 'lmodern' in my original latex document in order to show the \micro sign of 'siunitx' package. Is there a way to solve the problem of getting thicker font of text and math without eliminating previously used packages ? - since I included them because I needed them in the original document.

Comment: @user4861528 you should not need lmodern font to show the micro sign if you use the charter font. Did you try it without?

Comment: You are right. Your solution worked perfectly, and also the \micro sign of siunitx showed without the 'lmodern' package. Thank you very much !!

Comment: @user4861528 Glad to hear it's working!

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{load-configurations = abbreviations}
\sisetup{range-units=single}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[raggedright]{titlesec}
\usepackage{fixmath}

\begin{document}
...
\end{document}
```

[image]