# How to make the font weight of the math statements and equations match that of the text

Tags: fonts

The default weight of the font in the produced PDF document was a little slim and not easily readable.

I was advised to add to the preamble the line:

```
\usepackage{newtxtext}
```

and indeed the weight of the text font improved. However, the font of the mathematical equations and statements remained as slim as before. How can I make it match the weight of the text ?

A MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
%\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}
%\SetMathAlphabet{\mathcal}{normal}{OMS}{xmdcmsy}{m}{n}% use normal mathcal
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{load-configurations = abbreviations}
\sisetup{range-units=single}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[raggedright]{titlesec}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{fixmath}

\begin{document}
The binding energy of most atoms ($\sim$\SIrange[range-phrase={--}]{5}{15}{\electronvolt}) is about 5 to 10 times larger than the energy of an optical photon in the NIR region ($\sim$\SIrange[range-phrase={--}]{0.5}{1.5}{\electronvolt}). Some more text here. Bla bla bla. $\mathbf{A}$ and $\phi_{sc}$ are the vector and scalar potentials of the interacting electromagnetic field, and where the Coulomb gouge ($\nabla\cdot\mathbf{A}(\mathbf{r},t)=0$) is considered, $\phi_{sc}(\mathbf{r},t)\equiv\phi_C(\mathbf{r})=-e/4\pi\varepsilon_0 r$ is the Coulomb scalar potential (for simplicity a hydrogen atom is considered). And again some more text here. Bla bla bla bla. In a static external electric field of magnitude $\mathcal{E}_L$ in the x direction, the total potential exerted on a hydrogenic electron is: 

\begin{equation}
\phi_{st}=\frac{e}{4\pi\varepsilon_0 r}-x\mathcal{E}_L
\label{eq:electron_in_laser_field_potential}
\end{equation} %
%
and the corresponding electron electric potential energy, $U_E$, is writen blow but before lets put some more text between the equations in order to make the difference between the font weight of the text and the math (especially the greec symbols) more discernable. Bla bla bla bla bla bla. And now lets give the equation mentioned above which is:%
%   
\begin{equation}
U_E=-e\cdot\phi_{st}=-\frac{e^2}{4\pi\varepsilon_0 r}+ex\mathcal{E}_L
\label{eq:electron_in_laser_field_potential_energy}
\end{equation} %
%
This electric potential energy is shown in the figure below. And much more text goes here. Bla bla bla bla bla. And so on. 


\end{document}
```

Comment: "Related": https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/471648/105447

Comment: the newtxmath package has math fonts matching netwtxtext

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: So just to add the line: '\usepackage{newtxmath}' to the preamble?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: When I added the line '\usepackage{newtxmath}' to the preamble it didn't make the math statements more thicker, but what it did do is that some parenthesis that should have been in one of the math statements did not appear. I added a MWE to the question.

Comment: @user4861528 Same problem as in your other question, you are overwriting parts of the newtxmath font with the `lmodern` package. Remove it if you don't want to use Latin Modern font in your document.

Comment: don't load lmodern and also probably don't load fixmath (which is mostly aimed at computer modern use, which you are not using )

Comment: I also wouldn’t load `amssymb` together with `newtxmath`. If you’re loading multiple font packages, load the one you want to override the others last. In this case, you should load `newtxmath` after or instead of `amssymb` because `amssymb` has the wrong weight for this document.

Comment: A lot of people start out by copying someone else’s preamble and adding stuff to it. However it happened, you’ve ended up with some superfluous packages. I’d remove everything you don’t know for sure that you need, see what errors you get, and add packages back one by one to fix them.